# Is it possible to disable the quick time events (QTEs)?

Tags: accessibility, ratchet-and-clank-rift-apart

Insomniac's earlier game 'Spider-Man' (originally released in 2018 for PS4) features the option, according to [their support page](https://support.insomniac.games/hc/en-us/articles/360052412831-What-Accessibility-options-does-Marvel-s-Spider-Man-Miles-Morales-feature-):

> ##### Gameplay
>
> - QTE Auto Complete – Auto advance all QTE sequences without button presses.

The same feature is hinted in [a Sony accessibility blog post](https://www.sie.com/en/blog/inside-the-accessibility-features-of-ratchet-clank-rift-apart/) (dated May, 2021) for 'Ratchet & Clank: Rift Apart':

> Insomniac’s work on accessibility began with Marvel’s Spider-Man released in 2018. For our first foray into accessibility, we worked with consultants and focused on a short list of
> features that would have the biggest impact. This included high contrast subtitles, options for using button holds instead of rapid presses, and the ability to bypass QTE sequences
> and puzzles.

However, [the Insomniac support article for Rift Apart](https://support.insomniac.games/hc/en-us/articles/360061494611-What-Accessibility-options-does-Ratchet-Clank-Rift-Apart-feature-) doesn't contain the phrase.

I've seen several mentions online about a "disable / auto-complete quick time events" setting for the latest Ratchet title, but haven't been able to find any related option after a through search through the game options. Note that of Sony's first-party games, at least 'Uncharted: Legacy of Thieves Collection', 'Last of Us: Part 2' and 'God of War' (2018) have an accessibility feature for the QTEs (hold a button instead of rapidly pressing).

Comment: After having completed the game, there in fact are no QTEs in the campaign — I remember only on-screen prompts for using the wrench (unlock the path forward) after disabling tutorials. I assumed that the QTEs are present in every first-party Sony release. I don't know what to do with the question, I may expand this comment and post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As mentioned in your comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/399199/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-quick-time-events-qtes#comment561008_399199), there are no Quick Time Events in Ratchet & Clank: Rift Apart. However, there are accessibility options to slow the game down for events that require quick reaction times.

- Grind Assist: Automatically slows down time when nearing a hazard on grind rails (*Settings > Accessibility Settings > Toggles & Assists*)
- 70%/50%/30% Game Speed: Add a shortcut to decrease game speed (*Settings > Accessibility Settings > Shortcuts & Game Speed*)

[image: options to lower game speed]